# how to add a linefeed character after the first space after n characters in applescript

Tags: applescript

Hi is there anyway that I can put a linefeed after a number of characters, for example I have a text that have 200 chars, I want to add linefeed after each 20 characters, but I need to check that the character is not in the middle of a word, if it is, just add linefeed before that word.

is this possible with applescript?

Comment: It's too late here to write and test an answer, but try starting **Terminal** and running `man fmt` and `man fold` to see if one of those does what you want. Then use `set result to do shell script "fmt -w 80 something"`

Comment: thanks @MarkSetchell, the problem with the fmt is that I can't use a variable is input, for this script I don't want to have to put the texts in a file then reformat them & write to file & then read the file again, it make the process slow.
but also I didn't fine a solution that is possible to input a variable to fmt.

Comment: `fmt` will read from its `stdin` if no file is specified. So try this in **Terminal**, `echo "Some words long and short - a an at as if do by to in on" | fmt -w10`

Answer (score 1):

Using the first 200 characters of the contents of your post, here is one way of achieving the stated goal.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set myString to ¬
    "Hi is there anyway that I can put a  ¬
    linefeed after a number of characters, for example  ¬
    I have a text that have 200 chars, I want to add linefeed  ¬
    after each 20 characters, but I need to check that the"


foldTextToColumnsWithoutWordSplitting(myString, 20)


to foldTextToColumnsWithoutWordSplitting(textString, nCol)
    
    set processedString to paragraphs of ¬
        (do shell script "fold -sw " & nCol & " <<< " & textString's quoted form)
    
    set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
    set processedString to processedString as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
    
    return processedString
    
end foldTextToColumnsWithoutWordSplitting
```

**Which returns:**

> Hi is there anyway 
> that I can put a 
> linefeed after a 
> number of 
> characters, for 
> example I have a 
> text that have 200 
> chars, I want to 
> add linefeed after 
> each 20 characters, 
> but I need to check 
> that the

---

**Notes:**

The reason for processing what's returned from the `do shell script` *command* in this manner is so you actually have a *line feed* (`0A`), the expected **macOS** norm, at the end of each line, verses a *carriage return* (`0D`) otherwise.

The `paragraphs of` with the `do shell script` *command* creates an **AppleScript** *list*, which in essence removes the *carriage return* (`0D`) at the end of each line. Then the *list* is coerced into a *string* using a *line feed* (`0A`) after each *item* in the *list*, thus producing the wanted output.

Wrapping this in a *handler* keeps the *code* tidy and add the benefit of easily changing the *column width* when calling the *handler*.

If you are wanting to use this in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* in a **Run AppleScript** *action* where `input` will contain the *text string* to *fold*, the *handler* will need to be place outside of the `run` *handler*:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set myString to input as string
    
    set foldedText to my foldTextToColumnsWithoutWordSplitting(myString, 20)
    
    return foldedText
    
end run

to foldTextToColumnsWithoutWordSplitting(textString, nCol)
    
    set processedString to paragraphs of ¬
        (do shell script "fold -sw " & nCol & " <<< " & textString's quoted form)
    
    set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
    set processedString to processedString as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
    
    return processedString
    
end foldTextToColumnsWithoutWordSplitting
```